# Conditional Copy Rows macro formula

Tags: vba, excel, formula, conditional-statements

I am creating a spreadsheet tracking courier details. So I have 4 columns that says date, buyer, ETA and ETD. and I have a checkbox and I tick it if the package is received.

So, now if I tick checkbox, I want the entire row to shift to another sheet for completed packages.

Is there a formula to conditional shift row to another sheet or macro formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use formulas to *change* the display of Excel (hide / display row or column in particular).

Anyway, you can use **vba** to do what you want with a `Worksheet_change()` function within the `This_Workbook` module. You can find more info on the vba events on this [link](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/run-macros-change.htm).

To build a skeleton of your code, you can use the [macro vba recorder](http://zo-d.com/blog/archives/programming/writing-project-vba-macros-using-the-macro-recorder.html).

HTH,

Max